# html list hover moves other items

Tags: html, css

I am making a Menu page and i want it to look like this. (I've set a default img for all items for now).

Pizza

---

```
pizza1               pizza2          pizza3
imgPizza1            imgPizza2       imgPizza3
```

Salad

---

etc

I am using next code:

```
<div id="MainContent_panelItems">
   <br></br><br></br><br></br>
   <p class="menuTitle">Pizza</p>
   <hr>
   </hr>
   <ul class="foodItems">
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza Diavola</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza Quattro Formaggi</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza1RoPizza1RoPizza1Ro</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza2RoPizza2RoPizza2Ro</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza3RoPizza3RoPizza3Ro</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza4RoPizza4RoPizza4Ro</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza5RoPizza5Ro</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza6RoPizza6RoPizza6Ro</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Pizza7RoPizza7RoPizza7Ro</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <br></br><br></br><br></br>
   <p class="menuTitle">Paste</p>
   <hr>
   </hr>
   <ul class="foodItems">
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Spaghete Carbonara</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <br></br><br></br><br></br>
   <p class="menuTitle">Salate</p>
   <hr>
   </hr>
   <ul class="foodItems">
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Salată Caesar</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <br></br><br></br><br></br>
   <p class="menuTitle">Băuturi</p>
   <hr>
   </hr>
   <ul class="foodItems">
      <li style="height:100px;width:200px;">
         <p>Coca-Cola 0.5l</p>
         <img align="center" src="Images/orderedList1.png"></img>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foodItems li
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.foodItems li:hover
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #333;
    border-width: 1px;
}

p.menuTitle {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

it looks like this:
[image]

My problem is with the lines position and menuTitles and also when i hover over an item, the others move such in following picture:[image]

LE:
[image]

Comment: You don't have to use `display: inline;` if you are using `float`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, `border` is set only on `:hover`, so the overall `width` gets affected and the whole layout gets messed up. What you need to do is, set the `border-width` to `1px` in the normal state as well.

```css
.foodItems li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Or use `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: @chipChocolate.py True that. But I was also making sure it works with every other browsers. Old browsers do not support `box-sizing`.

Comment: thanks a lot, solved my moving items problem, but i also need the next foodTitle to be on a new row. how can i do that?

Comment: @bucurvlad Sure... Give a `clear: both` to the parent. Also, `overflow: hidden` does the trick.

Comment: @bucurvlad `<br></br><br></br><br></br>` this is invalid. There's no `</br>` tag. Same with `<hr></hr>` as there's no `</hr>` tag.

Comment: @Paulie_D pssst: I know people using IE 6 and the bugs come straight to me! :P

Comment: I create the html dynamically with a HtmlGeneric hr = new HtmlGeneric("hr"); and then add it to the panel.

i have a <div> <p> text </p> <img> </img>   </div>
how can i make the p and img on the center of the div.

LE: yes,it;s .NET

Comment: Oh... I don't know what's that. What's it? Is it .NET?

Comment: Yes. I solved the p with center='align', but the img won;t do so.

Comment: @bucurvlad Better to use `text-align: center` for the `<p>` and other things. Well, you need to change a lot of way you code. :) Your code looks ancient.

Comment: @bucurvlad Lemme know if there's any more issue in this.

Comment: well, the image is still not on the center of the div, sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110075/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-bucurvlad).

Comment: @bucurvlad Click on the above link and come to chat buddy.

Comment: @PraveenKumar can you answer me in chat, please?

Comment: i've sent you a message.